# JQuery Noty Message Bar Width

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have following script in my Codeigniter project to alert a message.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
noty({
                layout: 'top',
                type: 'warning',                
                text: '<?php echo $increments; ?>',
                dismissQueue: true,                 
                animation: {
                    open: {height: 'toggle'},
                    close: {height: 'toggle'},
                    easing: 'swing',
                    speed: 500 
                    },

                timeout: 0
                });
     });

</script>
```

The script is working fine and outs relevant message on the top of the screen. But I want to reduce the width of the message bar.

What can I change in my code to do that. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Are you using this library https://ned.im/noty/#/ ? And which version?

Comment: @  Brett Gregson. Yes. But didn't find the option to control the width of message bar

Comment: did you try to change the css (scss) file?